# iText PDF orientation

Tags: servlets, itext

I am using itextpdf version 5.0.1 to cut pages into specified page numbers.I am facing a problem when I try to cut a PDF which is oriented in landscape. When I use the following code the landscape oriented pdfs are getting cut like a potrait oriented pdf and the rest is missing. The code I am using is:

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
    public class PDFSplitExample {
    static void splitPdfFile(InputStream inputPdf,
                OutputStream outputStream, int startPage,
                int endPage) throws Exception{
            //Create document and pdfReader objects.
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPdf);
             //Get total no. of pages in the pdf file.
    int totalPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();

    //Check the startPage should not be greater than the endPage
    //and endPage should not be greater than total no. of pages.
    if(startPage > endPage || endPage > totalPages) {
       System.out.println("Kindly pass the valid values " +
            "for startPage and endPage.");
    }else{
         // Create writer for the outputStream
        PdfWriter writer = 
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

        //Open document
        document.open();

       //Contain the pdf data.
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = 
                writer.getDirectContent(); 
        PdfImportedPage page;

        while(startPage <= endPage) {
          document.newPage();
          page=writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader, startPage);
          pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
          startPage++;
        }

        //Close document and outputStream.
        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }          
}

public static void main(String args[]){
 try {          
    //Prepare output stream for 
    //new pdf file after split process.
        OutputStream outputStream1 = 
                new FileOutputStream("SplitFile1.pdf");
        OutputStream outputStream2 = 
                new FileOutputStream("SplitFile2.pdf");

        //call method to split pdf file.
        splitPdfFile(new FileInputStream("TestFile.pdf"),
                outputStream1, 1, 10);    
        splitPdfFile(new FileInputStream("TestFile.pdf"),
                outputStream2, 11, 20);  

        System.out.println("Pdf file splitted successfully.");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: For your task you should really use a `PdfCopy` based implementation (which among other advantages does not require you to control page rotation) instead of your `PdfWriter` based one.

Comment: I am not able to get what you are trying to say. Can you please explain it more elaborately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved my problem

```
    private static void manipulateWithCopy(PdfReader reader,String result)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));
    document.open();
    for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++i));
    }
    document.close();
}
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try{
    String path= "path/of/the/file/in/the/smb/storage";
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "username", "password");//storing authentication details
        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
        InputStream fileInputStream;
        String destFilename = "path/to/the/file";
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destFilename);
        fileInputStream = sFile.getInputStream();
        byte[] buf;
        int len;
        buf = new byte[16 * 1024 * 1024];
        while ((len = fileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        InputStream inputPdf = new FileInputStream(destFilename);
        PdfReader reader= new PdfReader(inputPdf);
        reader.selectPages(stpg+"-"+endpg);
        manipulateWithCopy(reader,destFilename);
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You reference "itextpdf version 5.0.1" - that version is extremely old and I have not worked with it for ages; I wrote the code below against a current 5.x version of iText (the 5.5.11 development branch). It might work with no or only minimal changes with older versions, too.*

Effectively your `splitPdfFile` method extracts a partial document of the given one. Instead of your approach (copying page content by page content to a new PDF), it is much easier to simply restrict the existing document to a subset of itself. This approach furthermore has the advantage that it does not have to separately deal with properties not from the page content, e.g. page rotations.

This bit of code, for example,

```
try (   InputStream resource = [...];
        OutputStream result = [...])
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resource);
    pdfReader.selectPages("2-4");
    new PdfStamper(pdfReader, result).close();
}
```

*([SubDocument.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/copy/SubDocument.java#L38) test method `testExtractSubDocument`)*

writes the pages 2, 3, and 4 from the input document to the result document.

---

A side note: Even for use cases which are not so simple, which e.g. collect pages from multiple source PDFs, using your approach is sub-optimal; instead of `PdfWriter` one should use a class from the `Pdf*Copy*` family of classes which also correctly copy page rotation.